# How to show hidden json with button?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have two buttons SHOW and HIDE. When show is clicked numbers will appear (which are json files, each json file contain only one number 1, 2, 3..) when HIDE is clicked first number(json) in a row dissapear. For example we clicked SHOW button 3 times and got this: 1 2 3 and then clicked HIDE once then we got: 2 3 shown. My problem is when HIDE is clicked I want to save that deleted number by showing it in my div where id="nome". After another clicking on button HIDE another hidden number is shown and old is deleted from div.

```js
var pageCounter = 1;
var pageCounterr = 1;
var animalContainer = document.getElementById("animal-info");
var animalContainerr = document.getElementById("nome");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var btnn = document.getElementById("btnn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://10.0.9.243/animals-' + pageCounter + '.json');
  ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    renderHTML(ourData);
  };
  ourRequest.send();
  pageCounter++;
});

function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString = document.createElement("div");
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let pText = document.createTextNode(data[i].name);
    let pElement = document.createElement("p");
    pElement.append(pText);
    htmlString.append(pElement);
    htmlString.classList.add('containers') // new Line added
  }
  animalContainer.append(htmlString);

}

btnn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let containers = document.getElementsByClassName('containers');
  if (containers.length > 0) {
    containers[0].remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">SHOW</button>
<button id="btnn">HIDE</button>
<h2>Numbers:</h2>
<div id="animal-info"></div>

<h2>Hidden number is:</h2>
<div id="nome"></div>
```

Comment: Assuming the retrieval works, please change the snippet I made into a [mcve]  - you can mock the values retrieved

Comment: Just insert the container into the div with id="nome" before deleting it.
Add:
`document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = containers[0];`

before `containers[0].remove();`

Comment: I did that, but nothing is shown in div with id="nome"

Comment: @PrincezicicaPrinci if your show function is working fine, the hide function much at least show [HTML Object] in the "nome".
Try using this code: `document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = containers[0].innerHTML`  this must be put under your btnn eventlistener

Comment: @LokendraSoni yes, it works now! A big thanks to you :)